# hystrix dashboard doesnt load metrix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hystrix, hystrix-dashboard

Experts,

In my spring boot 2.5.5 project with spring cloud version2020.0.4 and have configured Hystrix dashboard with the following dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have configured the fallbacks in the api gateway something like this

```
filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: My-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/myServiceFallBack
```

API gateway is running on port: 9191

So far it's good. When I access the API's via API Gateway I can see the CircuirtBreaker kicking in and the request getting forwarded to the 'fallback URI' when needed.

Now when I access

> http://localhost:9191/actuator/hystrix.stream

I can see pings listed there as well

I call the end-user API endpoints via the API Gateway.

However, when I try to see the Hystrix Dashboard it's just loading. I don't see any issues in the browser console or network tab.

Any idea what is gone wrong here.

[image]

Comment: 1. can you share the recording of the chrome developer console as well? I wanna see what calls are getting made to the backend server and whats is their response/status. It is possible that the backend is not flushing the response periodically due to which the dashboard is in the everlasting loading state.

2. are you caching any request/response in your spring application?

Answer (score -1):

As I can see the problem is that you are missing a dependency. `Hystrix` dashboard will provide `Hystrix stream` and that would be available via `Actuator` endpoint, therefore Actuator dependency is also needed. Please add the following dependency and try.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the following line to the application properties in-order to allow all the `Actuator` endpoints.

```
# Allow all Actuator endpoints
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

(Allowing all endpoints for testing purpose only and control access to each endpoint individually as required in production)